# Set the view to a specific cell

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

Do you know how to set the view to a specific cell in a `JTable`?
Because I'm working on searching for specific content in cells (Such Ctrl + F)

I have a specific cell such as row 39 and column 5, but I don't know how to view it

I have looked in `JTable` and `DefaultTableModel` but I don't see any useful methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Select (highlight) a specific JTable **Cell** then this could be one way you can do it:

```
public static void selectJTableCell(javax.swing.JTable theTable, 
                         int literalCellRowNumber, int literalCellColumnNumber) {
    /* Set the Selection mode...   */
    theTable.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    /* Make sure ColumnSelectionAllowed is enabled 
      so that just the cell is selected.        */
    theTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    /* Make sure RowSelectionAllowed is enabled. 
       (It should be by default anyways).     */
    theTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    /* Select the desired cell. We subtract 1 from 
       the supplied LITERAL Cell Row Number and the
       LITERAL Cell Column Number values supplied 
       since we're asking for the literal row/column
       numbers rather than index numbers. If you would 
       rather use an index value then remove the -1's.  */
    theTable.changeSelection(literalCellRowNumber - 1, literalCellColumnNumber - 1, false, false);
}
```

How you might use this method:

```
selectJTableCell(jTable1, 39, 5);
```

Consequently, if you want to select an entire JTable **Row**, then this could be one way you can do it:

```
public static void selectJTableRow(javax.swing.JTable theTable, int literalRowNumber) {
    /* Subtract 1 from the supplied LITERAL Row 
       Number value supplied since we're asking 
       for the literal row number rather than the 
       index number. If you would rather use an 
       index value then remove this code line.  */
    literalRowNumber = literalRowNumber - 1;
    /* Disable ColumnSelectionAllowed otherwise the 
       row will not be highlighted.        */
    theTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    /* Make RowSelectionAllowed is enabled.*/  
    theTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    /* Select the first cell in the desired row to 
       ensure the table will scroll to the row 
       selection so that it will be visible within 
       the viewport.                */
    theTable.changeSelection(literalRowNumber, 0, false, false);
    // Now, Select the row.
    theTable.setRowSelectionInterval(literalRowNumber, literalRowNumber);
    
}
```

How you might use this method:

```
selectJTableRow(jTable1, 39);
```